# Strange behavior of content negotiation concerning SPARQL CONSTRUCT query

Tags: sparql, jena, content-negotiation

When issuing a SPARQL CONSTRUCT query to a specific endpoint, Apache Jena library 3.14.0 issues an error message as follows.

> Endpoint returned Content Type: application/sparql-results+xml which is not a valid RDF syntax

The code I wrote is as follows.

```
QueryEngineHTTP qeh = new QueryEngineHTTP(endpointUrl, rq);
qeh.setAcceptHeader("application/rdf+xml");
Model m = qeh.execConstruct();
```

The endpoint is `https://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/sparql` .
The query is as follows.

```
CONSTRUCT {?s <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/vocab#altLabel> ?o}
FROM <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2020>
WHERE {
  ?s <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/vocab#altLabel> ?o ;
    a <http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/vocab#Term> .
  FILTER(isLiteral(?o))
} LIMIT 3
```

When issuing this query by the curl tool, I got a fine result.

```
% curl -LH 'Accept: application/rdf+xml' --data-urlencode query@test.rq https://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/sparql
```

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/vocab#">
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2020/T000963157">
    <j.0:altLabel xml:lang="en">Topics, Exhibitions as</j.0:altLabel>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2020/T000950545">
    <j.0:altLabel xml:lang="en">Psychiatric Fetishism</j.0:altLabel>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/2020/T000950541">
    <j.0:altLabel xml:lang="en">Psychological Extraversion</j.0:altLabel>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: you could try to add `qeh.setModelContentType(WebContent.contentTypeRDFXML);`

Comment: Thanks, but the result hasn't been changed.

Comment: "Endpoint returned Content Type: application/sparql-results+xml which is not a valid RDF syntax"  
so the other end returned a result set, it's not a content negotiation issue - maybe the query rq is a SELECT by accident.

Comment: I confirmed that the issued query was CONSTRUCT SPARQL query, not SELECT. I tried several times, so there was something wrong between the client and the server. I'd like to know more about what was going on between them.

Comment: Also I tried rsparql command and got the following

`$ rsparql --service https://id.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/sparql --query test.rq`
`org.apache.jena.query.QueryException: Endpoint returned Content Type: application/trig,application/n-quads;q=0.9,application/ld+json;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.3 which is not a valid RDF syntax`
`at org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execConstructWorker(QueryEngineHTTP.java:493)
...
`